# Sharepoint 2013 - custom word break

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, search, search-results

I have a large document library where the titles and names use hyphens to separate the words. I understand these are word breakers. To rename a library of this size is not practical.

Is there a way without touching the registry to achieve a custom word break?

I have documents setup such as the one below:

Name: CRV-002-userguide.pdf

Title: CRV-002-userguide

When the documents are searched it will return nothing if it is searched as **CRV-002** but will return values if search as **CRV 002**. I understand that the hyphen is a word breaker but I would like to know how to have it read as part of the string – as a character.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Sure - I will pop it in my question above.

Comment: Can you also update the what is the expected result because the question is little confusion?